# How to monitor systemd service with snmp?

Tags: systemd, snmp

So I have a Gunicorn service on my Ubuntu server.

First I added `proc gunicorn` to this file: `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.
But I'm not sure how to get the right values.

I've seen this question ([How to monitor services with SNMP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/867910/how-to-monitor-services-with-snmp)) and tried this command `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2` but I got this message:

`HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)`

So I guess the OID is wrong or I have other configurations.
How can I get the status of my services with snmp?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not able to see the corresponding output for process monitoring because of the `snmpd` daemon configuration (`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`)

```
# As shipped, the snmpd demon will only respond to queries on the
# system mib group until this file is replaced or modified for
# security purposes.
```

For **debugging purpose only**, you can configure the access control to be full open by editing `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

```
#       name           incl/excl     subtree         mask(optional)
view    allview      included   .1

#       group          context sec.model sec.level prefix read   write  notif
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  allview none none
```

Then restart the `snmpd` daemon.

```sh
systemctl restart snmpd
```

This is for debugging purpose only, for production the access control should be tuned to be less permissive.

Answer (score -2):

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c 209ijvfwer0df92jd -O e 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2
```

Comment: Where do you get this community string? What is the point of this answer? How would it help solve the problem?